# Manipulating a json file containing a dict of json string

Tags: python, json

I have a json file consisting of a dict of String:String

I tried to first load the file using json.load and then update the dict but when I dump the updated dict I lose the key. Unable to figure out how to update a value.

I'm trying to update the value of **sampleID** to something else and write back to the same file.

```
{"key":"{\"url\":\"DEFAULT\",\"id\":\"tzz22s6a\",\"sampleID\":\"jahsdioadhao\",\"isPassRequired\":false,\"isKeyRequired\":true,\"materialType\":\"SATIN\",\"clothType\":\"DEFAULT\"}"}
```

what I tried so far, which updates the value of sampleId but the format of the file is changed and also I loose the key i.e., **"key"**

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file_name)) as jsonFile:
    d = json.load(jsonFile)
    for values in d:
        data = json.loads(d[values])
        data['sampleID'] = 'newValue'

with open(os.path.join(root, file_name), 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `data` back to string and insert it back to the original dictionary

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file_name)) as jsonFile:
    d = json.load(jsonFile)
    for k in d:
        data = json.loads(d[k])
        data['sampleID'] = 'newValue'
        d[k] = json.dumps(data)

with open(os.path.join(root, file_name), 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(d, jsonFile, indent=4)
```

Output

```
{"key": "{\"url\": \"DEFAULT\", \"id\": \"tzz22s6a\", \"sampleID\": \"newValue\", \"isPassRequired\": false, \"isKeyRequired\": true, \"materialType\": \"SATIN\", \"clothType\": \"DEFAULT\"}"}
```

If you don't really need the `json` in this format, replacing `d[k] = json.dumps(data)` with `d[k] = data` will also give you a valid `json`.

Comment: ah thanks, this worked! I just had to dump it twice

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your nested json object isn't getting serialised properly from the sample JSON you provided.

To update the nested key you should modify it either in place inside the `d` object, or reassign `key` to the updated `data` JSON obj such as:

```py
with open(os.path.join(root, file_name)) as jsonFile:
    d = json.load(jsonFile)
    for key in d:
        # You shouldn't need to load this again on the line below if the input json is valid but in your example it is not.
        data = json.loads(d[key])
        data['sampleID'] = 'newValue'
        # Set "key" in d to be the updated data dict.
        d[key] = data
```

Additional points:

- The iterator of `d` will loop through the keys so I changed it to `for key in d` to make it clearer.
- Your nested JSON in the pasted example isn't value due to the backslash characters so to reproduce your code I did this:

```py
import json
import re

data = {"key":"{\"url\":\"DEFAULT\",\"id\":\"tzz22s6a\",\"sampleID\":\"jahsdioadhao\",\"isPassRequired\":false,\"isKeyRequired\":true,\"materialType\":\"SATIN\",\"clothType\":\"DEFAULT\"}"}

# Create a regex compiler
pattern = re.compile(r"\\")

# Sub the characters in pattern with empty string `""` in place on data["key"]
pattern.sub("", data["key"])

# Set data["key"] in place to be the dict of the json string.
data["key"] = json.loads(data["key"])

# Replace the value of "sampleID" in "key"
data["key"]["sampleID"] = "newValue"

# which produces
{'key': {'url': 'DEFAULT',
  'id': 'tzz22s6a',
  'sampleID': 'newValue',
  'isPassRequired': False,
  'isKeyRequired': True,
  'materialType': 'SATIN',
  'clothType': 'DEFAULT'}}
```